# В двумерном массиве перед элементами X вставить 2

Tags: c++, массивы

Пользователь вводит двумерный массив char символами. Перед каждым `X` вставить число `2`. И вывести его.
Ввод : 
`X u y X 
x z g H
D a f X
X u y Y`
Вывод : 
`2 X u y 2 X 
x z g H
D a f 2 X
2 X u y Y`
Трудность в решении этой задачи у меня возникает в том, что нужно расширять на определенное количество соответствующую строку.
Можно попробовать вытащить строку из массива и работать уже над ней, как над одномерным массивом.
Получилось решить эту задачу для одномерного массива.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int size; cout << " Enter size = " ; cin >> size;

  char *before = new char[size];

    int new_size = size;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << " [" << i << "] = "; cin >> before[i];
        if (before[i] == 'X') {
            new_size++;
        }
    }

    char *after = new char[new_size];
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (before[i] == 'X') {
            after[j++] = '2';
        }
        after[j++] = before[i];
    }

    delete [] before;
    for (int i = 0; i < new_size; i++) {
        cout << after[i];
    }
    delete [] after;
}
```

Не могу придумать, как решить ее для двумерного массива, ведь повторюсь, нужно увеличивать размер определенной строки массива.

Спасибо!

Comment: Как создавать динамический массив можно узнать из учебников, погуглив или смотрев многочисленные примеры в SO

Comment: Уважаемый @AR Hovsepyan, я знаю как создать динамический двумерный массив. Пожалуйста, перечитайте мой вопрос снова.

Comment: Если знаете, так пишите, покажите что вы пытались делать, и  в каом месте трудность.

Comment: Смог решить эту задачку для одномерного массива. Алгоритм был такой : найти количество символов X в первом массиве и прибавить из к его размеру (это будет размер нового массива). После если такой символ встречается в первом массиве, то в новый массив вставить на соответствующее место 2. Далее - копируем все элементы. Тут так не получается, т.к. размер будет применяться для всех строк, а не для конкретной. Именно поэтому обратился на этот форум. К тому же, я написал в вопросе в чем у меня трудности в решении этой задачи.

Comment: Уважаемый  Boris Makhlin, впишите в вопрос как вы решили для одномерного массива, впишите все то, что вы пытались делать.  Двумерный массив от одномерного различается только тем, что он содержит  несколько таких массивов, и для каждой строки вы должны делать то же самое, что делали для одномерного массива

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: теперь другой дело: вопрос звучит нормально, но лично я смогу вам ответить поздно вечером...

Comment: Можно взять std::vector<std::string> и использовать метод insert. Или нужно вручную делать?

Comment: @Beaver Feller, нужно реализовать вручную

Comment: У задачи странная постановка. Концепция "двумерного массива", как структуры данных, не предполагает существования такой операции, как "увеличить строку массива". Двумерный массив - это матрица, массив "N на M". Строки двумерного массива не являются увеличиваемыми независимо, по определению. Вам, судя по всему, нужен "рваный" массив (jagged array), т.е. массив массивов, а не двумерный массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть ваш `before` будет не указателем на массив символов,  а указателем  на динамический массив указателей , и тогда вы можете ваш же код выполнять циклически для каждого элемента  `before` .  Но так как ваш код не выводит старый массив, то лучше сразу создать массив на 1 элемент больше. И нужно не забывать выделять место для символа конца строки в массивах символов. Таким образом можно на основе вашего кода написать новый:

```
int row;
cout << "Enter number of arrays\n";
cin >> row;
//массив указателей
char** before = new char*[row];    
int size;
char c;
cout << " Enter size = " ;
cin >> size;
// для каждого массива выполняем наш код
for (int k = 0; k < row; ++k) {
    // каждый элемент, это указатель. 
    //пусть он указывает на массив размером
    // на 1  больше плюс место для '\0'
    before[k] = new char[size + 2]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << " [" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> c;
        if (c == 'X') {
            before[k][i] = '2';
            before[k][++i] = c;
        }
        before[k][i] = c;
    }
}
//вывод и удаление
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        cout << before[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    delete before[i];
}
delete before;
```

P.S. Вам вовсе и не нужно было создавать массив в куче, а просто на стеке

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char* insertBefore(char *before, char chFind, char chInsert) {
    size_t len = strlen(before);
    size_t new_size = len;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (before[i] == chFind) {
            new_size++;
        }
    }
    char *after = new char[new_size + 1]; // +1 для '\0'
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < len + 1; i++) {
        if (before[i] == chFind) {
            after[j++] = chInsert;
        }
        after[j++] = before[i];
    }
    delete[] before;
    return after;
}

int main()
{
    size_t rows, columns;
    cout << "rows = ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "columns = ";
    cin >> columns;

    char **matr = new char*[rows];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        matr[i] = new char[columns + 1]; // +1 для '\0'
        for (size_t j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cin >> matr[i][j];
        }
        matr[i][columns] = '\0';
        matr[i] = insertBefore(matr[i], 'X', '2');
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        size_t len = strlen(matr[i]);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            cout << matr[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```